# How to break coroutine on Exception in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I want to escape if CoTest_B has Exception or onFail and don't read CoTest_C() Code
But after Excpetion and onFail, Coroutine still reading las

```
IEnumerator CoTest_B( Action onSuccess , Action onFail )

IEnumerator CoTest Main()
{
     yield return CoTest_A();
     yield return CoTest_B();
     yield return CoTest_C();
}
```

I tried use boolean but it make code dirty

Comment: the best option would probably be to not use Coroutines but `Task`s

Comment: You can use [StopCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html)

Comment: I agree that Coroutines are not suited to this pattern. Tasks are difficult in Unity, though, because you can run into problems when trying to manipulate engine code or things that interact with it from another thread. It looks like you are trying to follow the Promise pattern; there are some libraries that do this, like: https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise . If you prefer something like tasks, there is also UniTask: https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask